# Comparing segmentation, paging, and partitioning - memory management and swapping processes

Tags: linux, macos, unix, memory-management, operating-system

As I understand it, when processes are swapped-out of main memory and then back in, they can occupy different regions of physical memory. Is this ability shared by all three of segmentation, paging, and partitioning memory management systems? If not, what are the differences and why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing a lot of of different concepts. Segmentation is an obsolete system for managing memory. In ye olde days when a large system had 1–2 MB of memory and 16-bit addressing, a process could only access a fraction of the system memory (64Kb). Segment registers were used to access larger address ranges (at different times). Segmentation could be used to support multiple processes or it could be used to increase the available memory in a single process. While the process was limited to 64KB at any one time, playing with segment registers would allow a process to have more than 64KB of memory (total) available to it. This was a common practice on PDP-11s.

Partitioning and segmenting are essentially the same and are equally obsolete. I described the PDP as using segments. Others describe it as using partitions. There are multiple versions of partitions.

Intel kept (and keeps in 32-bit mode) segmentation alive long after it should have died out in its processors.

Swapping is an obsolete system for implementing multi-processing. The entire process gets moved to disk. In the days of 64KB processes this did not have the overhead that moving a 32-bit address space to disk would have.

Modern systems use paging for memory management. In virtual memory systems, individual pages are moved to secondary storage; not entire processes (although it is possible for an entire process to be paged out of memory).

Comment: Thanks for the response. My original post was unclear, but I didn't necessarily mean that we have to swap entire processes. As you say, its superior to instead swap specific pages or segments themselves. So you're saying that partitioning and segmentation memory management systems are actually the same thing?

Comment: Also, my question specifically pertains to the order of physical memory storage after swapping has occurred in these 3 (2?) systems of memory management. For instance, if we swap out parts of the process image using paging or segmentation (obsolete), in what order are they swapped back? Can both systems of memory management swap parts of the process image back into different (from their original) locations of main memory?

Comment: In swapping the entire process gets written or read. You don't normally swap out parts of a process. Paging moves parts of the process to secondary storage.

Comment: I see. So paging and swapping are actually two completely different systems of memory management?

Comment: They are the same in that they save memory to disk. They are different in how they do that saving. In the days of 64K memory, paging did not make any sense because you could read the whole process in just a few I/O operations.

Comment: Thanks. What about the original question? Under these systems, when parts of the process image is moved from main memory, to secondary memory, and back to main memory again, can they then occupy different (from their original) regions of main memory?

Comment: In virtual (page_ memory systems, all process memory (except system space where parts may be non-paged) have a backing on secondary storage. In most systems the disk space is allocated before the memory is allocated. In a paged system, they can occupy different locations in memory. 

In a segment/partition system, it is possible to go back the same memory after swapping but the larger the physical memory, the less likely it will be to return to the same place.